# Plot time series data by variable with multiple colour geom_area simultaneously using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

With a data sample as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18901, 18902, 18903, 18904, 
18905, 18906, 18907, 18908, 18909, 18910, 18911, 18912, 18913, 
18914), class = "Date"), value = c(190.3, 174.9, 163.2, 168.4, 
168.6, 168.2, 163.5, 161.6, 172.9, 166.5, 175.2, 197.7, 212.1, 
177.9), type = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```

First I convert `type` and `date` to appropriate data type:

```
df$type <- as.factor(df$type)
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
```

I'm try to draw this time series data simultaneously based on `type` with different colours.

The problem is I can't set customized colours and gap between areas are a little bit large.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=date, y=value, group=type)) + 
  geom_area(fill=df$type, alpha=0.4) +
  geom_line(color=df$type, size=1) +
  geom_point(size=2, color=df$type) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("gray", "red", "blue"))
```

Out:

[image]

How could reproduice a figure similar to effect below? Sincere thanks.

[image]

Comment: What elements from the example do you want to capture which you haven't already?  The x and y axis range just showing extremes? The title of the question makes me think there's something else to it.

Comment: First thing, I think it should be customized colours and gap between different areas (which is too large as you may notice). For x and y axis labels, maybe I need to ask a new question. But if you can answer at once, it will be the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the colors, I'd suggest:

```
df$type = as.factor(df$type)
ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=value, group=type, 
            color = type, fill = type)) + 
  geom_area(alpha=0.4) +
  geom_line(size=1) +
  geom_point(size=2) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("1" = "gray", "2" = "red", "3" = "blue"), 
                     aesthetics = c("color", "fill"), name = "type")
```

[image]

EDIT - to remove the gaps, we could repeat the first entries of each `type` and assign them to the prior `type`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(type = lag(type),
         date = date - 0.0001) %>% # w/o this the values stack at boundaries
  bind_rows(df) %>%


ggplot(aes(x=date, y=value, group=type, 
               color = type, fill = type)) + 
...
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe use `df$type <- as.factor(df$type)` to convert `type` from integer to factor at first for `df`? and to adjust the `gap`?

Comment: For the gap, do you want the shading to continue past each `type`'s last value up to the next one? I'm trying to think of a non-hacky way to do that. Best I can think of initially is to copy each boundary value and give it the prior row's type, but that feels kludgy.

Comment: Similar to the plot in the end of question will be cool, not nessary to be exact same.

Comment: BTW, the values between different type not need to be continuous in the plot.

Comment: Sorry, I get an error: `Error: Problem with mutate() column date.
i date = date - 1e-04. x non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: Btw, is it possible to extend the gap between areas type 1 and type 2 as shown by example plot?